# How to append the objects/array to another object in js function in karate

Tags: karate

```
Feature: Append object/array to another object in karate js function

  Scenario: s1

* def finalResponse = {}
* def fun =
"""
function(object)
{
for (var i=0; i<object.length;i++) {

var data = [{'language':'JS'},{'framework':'karate'}]

object[i].optionTranslationListItems = data
```

`finalResponse = finalResponse.add(object[i]) // This line does not work, need to append` the objects to finalResponse object declared at line 5

print("finalResponse ",JSON.stringify(finalResponse))

```
}


}

    """
    * def jsonReq =
    """
   [
  {
  "id": 1,
  "optionValue": "value1",
  "optionCode": "code1",
  "optionNumber": 1,
  "status": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "optionValue": "value2",
  "optionCode": "code2",
  "optionNumber": 2,
  "status": "ACTIVE"
  }
  ]
    """

    * fun(jsonReq,fun)
```

finalResponse variable declared at line 5 should store all the objects.

Comment: This has been resolved. instead of finalResponse = finalResponse.add(object[i]), just need to use finalResponse[i]=object[i]